# Is a nested yield or conversion to block faster?

Tags: ruby, yield

In Ruby, it is quite often said that `yield` is faster than converting a block into a `Proc`.

For example:

```
def method
  yield
end
```

Is faster than

```
def method &block
  block.call
end
```

However, what if a block needs to be passed as an argument several layers deep? Is `yield` always faster no matter how many layers deep you pass it down? Does it depend on how many layers, or does it depend on the number of variables in each closure?

The reason I ask is because to `yield` several layers deep involves wrapping it into a block multiple times, whereas converting it to a `Proc` may save time by only doing it once. I also want to know whether it depends on how many variables need to be packaged up in the `to_proc` method.

Thus, which is faster:

The nested yield?

```
def method1;method2 {yield};end
def method2;method3 {yield};end
  ...
def methodn;yield;end
```

Or the `&block`?

```
def method1 &block;method2 &block;end
def method2 &block;method3 &block;end
  ...
def methodn &block;block.call;end
```

Comment: where did you read that?

Comment: Converting to a Proc does supposedly cost some time, but why don't you just benchmark it? http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html

Answer (score 0):

```
require "benchmark"

def test_yield
    yield
end

def test_block(&block)
    block.call
end

Benchmark.bm do |b|

    b.report("test_yield") {
        10000.times{ test_yield {1+1} }
    }

    b.report("test_block") {
        10000.times{ test_block {1+1} }
    }

end



      user     system      total        real
test_yield  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.002623)
test_block  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.009497)
```

It seems like Yield is faster than block.call. I would love to understand why though.

Comment: It's slower because declaring a block param allows you to do more things than without it (you can call methods on the [`Proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Proc.html), such as `#binding`, you can even arbitrarily read/modify the captured variables in the binding!). To support this, a `Proc` object needs to be allocated. If you don't declare an explicit block param, and you only use `yield`, all you can do is call the block. In that case, the VM can skip the allocation of the `Binding` and `Proc`.